# list of buttons created by ng-repeat: collect states under one array in the $scope model?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of angular-bootstrap buttons made using ng-repeat:

```
  <div class="btn-group">
     <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="???what to insert???"  btn-checkbox
       ng-repeat="station in stationlist">{{station.name}}</label>
  </div>
```

where I want to insert something in ng-model, that would give me in the end an associative array, e.g., buttons[key] = true|false. Key must be e.g. station.name, that is, derived from ng-repeat object.

Note that these angular-bootstrap buttons insert true|false to connected ng-model variables; see example: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons. The problem is that I need  to have an array element in the model, so later I want iterate on the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this :

```
$scope.stationlist = [
    { name: 'a', checked: true },
    { name: 'b', checked: false },
    { name: 'c', checked: true },
    ...
];
```

And bind it like :

```
<label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="station.checked" btn-checkbox
  ng-repeat="station in stationlist">{{station.name}}</label>
```

Comment: You probably meant stationList to be array of objects. As current code has syntax error